# Optimizing select count query if number of matching rows greater than number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running `Postgresql` table with multiple millions of rows. To simplify the problem lets assume that table has only 2 columns: `ID`(primary key) and `TYPE`. There is additional index created on `TYPE` column.
I run query which counts values in the table for given type:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM table where TYPE= 'XX';
```

The query works fine, however as the table is big it uses resources and takes significant time already. My actual use case does not need exact count if it is greater than 50. Is there a way to optimize this query in `Postgresql`, so it returns values from 0 to 50 and if it is greater it skips counting?

Or the only way to improve the performance is to store aggregate count in other table?

Comment: count is notorious slow, so if you really need that count make another table with the count and write triggers for it, that will keep an accurate count and will be fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get high performance by adding the index:

```
create index ix1 on table (type, id);
```

Then the query can take the form:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select id from table where type = 'XX' limit 51
) x;
```

In this query the index scan  will be limited to `51` index entries. The count -- done in the external query -- will return values between 0 and 51. If it's 51, then it means there are more than 50 ids for that type.